# Google API BadAuthentication error with Zend gdata

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-contacts-api

I am using gdata to add contacts to my gmail account using the Contact API.  When I run the code on my development box as localhost, everything works fine.  But when I move the code to a production server (www.somedomain.com) I get "ERROR:Authentication with Google failed. Reason: BadAuthentication".

Here's my code:

```
<?php
// load Zend Gdata libraries
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Feed');

// set credentials for ClientLogin authentication
$user = "something@gmail.com";
$pass = "somepassword";

try {
  // perform login and set protocol version to 3.0
  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
    $user, $pass, 'cp');
  $gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
  $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

  // create new entry
  $doc  = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->formatOutput = true;
  $entry = $doc->createElement('atom:entry');
  $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,
   'xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
  $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,
   'xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
   $entry->setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$entry->setAttribute('xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$entry->setAttribute('xmlns:gContact', 'http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008');
  $doc->appendChild($entry);

  // add name element
  $name = $doc->createElement('gd:name');
  $entry->appendChild($name);
  $fullName = $doc->createElement('gd:fullName', 'Jack Frost');
  $name->appendChild($fullName);

  // add email element
  $email = $doc->createElement('gd:email');
  $email->setAttribute('address' ,'jack.frost@example.com');
  $email->setAttribute('rel' ,'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home');
  $entry->appendChild($email);

  // add org name element
  $org = $doc->createElement('gd:organization');
  $org->setAttribute('rel' ,'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');
  $entry->appendChild($org);
  $orgName = $doc->createElement('gd:orgName', 'Winter Inc.');
  $org->appendChild($orgName);

  //add to Friends list
  $group = $doc->createElement('gContact:groupMembershipInfo');
        $group->setAttribute('deleted' ,'false');
        $group->setAttribute('href' ,'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/' .urlencode($user) . '/base/[groupid]'); 


 //addd to my contacts       
$entry->appendChild($group);

 $group = $doc->createElement('gContact:groupMembershipInfo');
 $group->setAttribute('deleted' ,'false');
 $group->setAttribute('href' ,'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/' .urlencode($user) . '/base/6');  //adds to Friends

$entry->appendChild($group);

  // insert entry
  $entryResult = $gdata->insertEntry($doc->saveXML(), 
   'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
  echo '<h2>Add Contact</h2>';
  echo 'The ID of the new entry is: ' . $entryResult->id;
  echo 'The link is: <a href="'.$entryResult->getLink('edit').">".$entryResult->getLink('edit')."</a>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR:' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Should I be using OAuth for Services instead?  I haven't been able to find documentation on how to do this with Zend Gdata.

EDIT - ANSWER FOUND:

Ok - I still have a question about a better auth method but I figured out what the issue was in this case.  Google was suspicious of my application logging in.  When I checked gmail, I had received the following:

```
Hi Info, 

Someone recently used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account [someone]@gmail.com. This person was using an application such as an email client or mobile device. 

We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt: 

Saturday, November 2, 2013 9:43:52 PM UTC 
IP Address: [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] ([xxx.xxx.xx.xxx].unifiedlayer.com.) 
Location: Unknown


If you do not recognize this sign-in attempt, someone else might be trying to access your account. You should sign in to your account and reset your password immediately. 

Reset password  

If this was you, and you are having trouble accessing your account, complete the troubleshooting steps listed at http://support.google.com/mail?p=client_login 

Sincerely,
The Google Accounts team
```

I went into gmail security (through the link provided) and was able to authorize the app.  Problem solved.  Works perfectly now.

I'd still like some pointers on how to use my Client ID, Service Account and Private Key with Zend (if possible).  I have connected using the Google API php library but I can't see how to use this within the Zend framework.

Comment: Same thing happened with me today while using Zend to login to YouTube.  Thanks for posting the solution!

Comment: Google shows my activity flagged as my own, but is still denying my app access with the "BadAuthentication" message. Hrm.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I solved the problem by entering my full email address as username (username@gmail.com).

Previously, I tried to access to my account only with the username...